# Sending and getting commands through the Internet

Tags: motor, wireless, signal, wifi

I have a little chopper (adult toy to be exact) that can be controlled by the controller within 30 metres. What I have in my mind whether I can send commands to this toy chopper though the Internet, a website (maybe fetches the HTML or php code) or whatever--the chopper will use the Internet just like we use the Internet on our cellphones. Briefly, Instead of pushing "turn right" button on the controller, I want to send that command through the Internet so that it will have a very large range, or unlimited, to be contolled.

I am an engineering student so I want to build something touchable right now:) The problem is that I dont know where to start. I would google it but I don't even know keywords to search for. So even little push would be great. Which devices should I use, which language should I know, exactly, what is next I should do now?

I hope I am not asking this question in wrong place.

Comment: When you say 'chopper', do you mean helicopter?  Or is this a sex toy?

Comment: Mentating: 30 metres range - it's a helicopter :-)

Comment: Do you need to be able to get feedback from the toy? Will the toy always be in range of its controller, or are you looking to re-build the controller?

Comment: Noo:DDafdsvsxdfvsdfsd It is a helicopter about 50 cm. And, it flies, my friend,with a controller. The problem is with that controler there is a range. I want to increase it with the help of the Internet

Comment: @RussellMcMahon : There are also sex toys with a range of several meters. http://www.lovehoney.co.uk/product.cfm?p=15667

Comment: @rocketmagnet, I want to replace the job of controller with the Internet

Comment: Increasing range with these sort of toys is often a matter of using correctly (better) sized antenna's ;o) But is it correct to understand our computer controls the controller or do you want to build another controller or do you want your chopper to use an entirely different receiver than it is using now?

Comment: @jippie Entirely different receiever i guess. Because, changing the type of the controller will only increase my range at most 100 metres. What i want is to make it unlimited. In other words, where the chopper can connect the Internet, It can be controlled:) Is it possible?

Comment: İ mean with "is it possible?" that "can it be done with my knowledge"?--enginnering student. I dont think NASA will help me for that:)

Comment: Sure it can be done, even without help from NASA. Thing is you should set yourself goals that you know you can reach with a bit of experimenting/fiddling around, reading a bit etc. Make yourself a plan in babysteps how to reach the final goal. For instance you could start by trying to control the chopper through a couple of wires from your PC or a microcontroller. Surely it can't fly while wired up, but it is probably the first step. You probably want to start experimenting with a microcontroller too, unless your chopper can carry a laptop ;o)

Comment: @user893970 - Can you give us a link to a description of the helicopter?

Comment: @user893970 Note that if you want to safely investigate this course of action, spend some time thinking about what will happen in case of dropped packets, lag and other problems Internet introduces. Most helicopters are designed so that the operator is constantly using the remote control and very few have any sort of automatic recovery. You may fist need to take a look at autopilots available. There are even some open hardware/ open source systems for which you can download schematics and source code. After you have that running try sending commands to the system over Internet.

Answer (score 2):

Think about what you want to build. Are you firing commands into the blue (from the website) or do you use a camera for feedback? If you use a camera (or even GPS), think about the delays involved. A too large delay will render the remote control unusable. All in all it sounds quite complicated for a beginner project in electronics. Maybe you check out the [Arduino](http://arduino.cc/) ... it will make build something "touchable" (as you stated your intention) way easy. The [Ethernet Shield](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoEthernetShield) will make hooking things up to the internet a piece of cake.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an internet connected helicopter, you'll need something like the [Microchip MRF24WB0MA](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70632B.pdf) RF transceiver module.

[image: Microchip MRF24WB0MA]

However, integrating this with the helicopter's electronics will not be easy. The helicopter contains a circuit like this:

```
RF Receiver -> IC -> Motors
Gyro sensor ->
```

The IC would probably be a microcontroller or ASIC which contains the control algorithms for keeping the helicopter stable. You have two options to add your internet controller:

1. Find a way to inject RF commands in to the microcontroller. This is probably the hardest method, as you will need to reverse-engineer the RF protocol used by the helicopter.
2. Replace the microcontroller with your own. Yours would communicate with the WiFi device, and handle all of the helicopter's control algorithms.
3. Add another microcontroller which communicates with the WiFi device, and modifies the gyro signals to cause the original microcontroller to move the helicopter. This will be tricky.

Sadly, none of these approaches are really easy. As others have suggested, you might just be better off trying to boost the output of the original controller, so that it has more range.

Comment: While at first sight this may all look complicated, radio protocols used by popular manufacturers of radio equipment tend to be well documented. Another thing which needs to be mentioned here is that bigger helicopters which don't use n-in-one units usually have standardized communication between each subsystem and it would be relatively easy to replace receiver with a home-made one  and keep the rest of the circuitry unmodified. [This](http://www.rcgroups.com/diy-electronics-199/) forum is a good place to start looking.

Comment: @AndrejaKo - If this were a traditional servo controlled helicopter, then I would agree with you. However, I suspect this is one of the new fangled kind with gyro stabilisation. Assuming the OP wants to keep the gyro aspect, then he will have to implement some kind of active control in the MCU.

Comment: Actually, from what I've seen, the usual setup is to have a separate the "receiver module" into which the servos, electronic speed controller and gyroscope are plugged in. The Rx module often consists of a separate receiver PCB that only receives the data from the Tx and sends it to micro for processing. The signals themselves aren't too complicated. My idea is to replace that board with our own and do whatever processing is needed before sending the data to the MCU.

Comment: Another option would be to create our own receiver which would get the data which the original Rx creates and change them to suit our own needs and connect the ESC and servos to it. This way, it would be possible to have both control over original transmitter and to use one custom made. Of course the specifics would depend on the exact system used on the helicopter.

Comment: @AndrejaKo - Also, I'm guessing that this helicopter does *not* use a standard transmitter (futaba etc, which would be well documented). I don't know if [toy helicopters](http://www.heliguy.com/Electric-RC-Helicopters/ESKY-Big-Lama/Main-Group/) have well documented protocols.

Comment: @AndrejaKo - Yes, we'd certainly need to know more about the heli to know what kind of options are suitable.

Comment: Actually, if I remember correctly, some guy on RC groups reverse-engineered the protocol for communication between the receiver PCB and the rest of the 4-in-1 unit for Lava V4 and derivatives. I think that the same protocol is used in Big Lama, except  it has separate receiver plus a 3-in-1 unit. The protocol was pretty simple, and from what I remember, an oscilloscope (which is something the OP hopefully has access to) was enough to reverse-engineer it. In the thread, there was even a project which used an 8bit AVR to work with the receiver.

Comment: Still, a lot depends on what OP actually has. For all we know, it could be just a huge IR controller helicopter (which might even be correct after taking range in account).

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately the range is determined by the uplink (or uplinks) to the heli - IR, RF, ultrasonic whistle or whatever else.  Are you trying to build something analogous to a cellular command system, using the highest quality link available from many ground stations, all communicating over the internet?  Because otherwise, the uplink and its range are unaffected by whether the control commands are inserted directly in the ground-station, as in a typical RC transmitter, or arrived from half-way 'round the planet over the internet.  The heli's radius of action will around the ground station will remain the same; only your (personal) range would be increased.

If you are going for a cellular network, you've got a very interesting, fun, and very non-trivial project ahead of you.